# Off-line notification by date

Tags: android, date, notifications

Please advise me how to do better. In my program there are reminders by date. How do I send Notification that when you click on the notification to the user is taken to the screen with the program? It gets through the calendar to the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Use notification manager as in link below
http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

let me know if you need a detail example.

Comment: How I can make notification wich started after one week with Notification Manager?

Comment: Actually you have to get pick a date by user if you want to make a notification whenever you want then you have to use a push notification